# Why is my Event Timeline chart in Quiver not colored by the event property I selected?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have an Event Timeline widget in my Quiver Analyses that shows multiple events. I selected them to be colored by a specific event property but all the events still appear in the same color. Why is the coloring not working?
[image: Timeline not colored]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Events Timeline chart won't support coloring if the number of events shown exceeds the "Raw/Single Event Threshold". That said, to make the coloring work in your case, you have two options:

1. You can increase the raw event threshold. Note: the higher you set this number, the less performant the widget will be.[image: Low threshold coloring][image: high threshold coloring]
2. You can zoom in to reduce the number of events in the view. [image: Zoomed in]